# A dynamically updating graph for PyQt GUI

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, dynamically-generated

I have developed a Qt GUI using Qt4 and PyQt. I am trying to implement a graph that will dynamically "live update" the graph to represent the rate at which the data is being transmitted in a (data/sec format). However, the problem lies within implementing a graph that can cleanly live update, not finding the speed. For the record, I want this to be built in as a widget within the GUI not a separate pop-up window.

Comment: I've generally found matplotlib slow for displaying live data. I believe pyqtgraph is faster, but must admit I haven't tried live updating with pyqtgraph myself (only saw an example while I was using it for something else)

Comment: MatPlotLib ended up working, I simply redrew the graph once a second but limited the x axis to only display 10 points. While inefficient, it will work for my purposes

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use two threads: One for acquiring data from somewhere, the other for representing it's graphics. You can take a look on [A “live” data monitor with Python, PyQt and PySerial](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/08/07/a-live-data-monitor-with-python-pyqt-and-pyserial/) or to [pyQt Matplotlib widget live data updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877371/pyqt-matplotlib-widget-live-data-updates).

Comment: I have been attempting to use the pyQt Matplotlib widget, and while it can recognize the data is coming in, it is having trouble with .draw(). The x and y axis change their size, but aside from that there is no visual difference. I will look over my code again.

Answer (score 0):

I've used qCustomPlot ([website here](http://www.qcustomplot.com/)) with pretty good success. I can live-update several thousand data points and it's all very straightforward to use.

Comment: Straightforward to use from PyQt?

Comment: There exists a PyQt binding to QCustomPlot; https://github.com/dimV36/QCustomPlot-PyQt5.