# Matplotlib is not recognizing the attribute set_xdata.

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, matplotlib-basemap

In reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877371/pyqt-matplotlib-widget-live-data-updates/23883811#comment37569428_23883811): I have been attempting to run the following code for plotting and live updating a graph. However, I am welcomed by the following error every time I attempt to run the function: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_xdata'`

The rest of the function looks like the following:

```
def getData(self):
    self.data = random.gauss(10,0.1)
    self.ValueTotal.append(self.data)
    #With value total being a list instantiated as ValueTotal = []
    self.updateData()

def updateData(self):

    if not hasattr(self, 'line'):
        # this should only be executed on the first call to updateData
        self.widget.canvas.ax.clear()
        self.widget.canvas.ax.hold(True)
        self.line = self.widget.canvas.ax.plot(self.ValueTotal,'r-')
        self.widget.canvas.ax.grid()
    else:
        # now we only modify the plotted line
        self.line.set_xdata(np.arange(len(self.ValueTotal)))
        self.line.set_ydata(self.ValueTotal)

    self.widget.canvas.draw()
```

While this code originated from [sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319400/sebastian) and [Jake French](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978467/jake-french) I have not had any success implementing this.Is there something I am doing wrong? What generates this error and how can I fix?

This is used strictly for an example and will not be copied into my code. I am simply using it for referential material and felt this would be the simplest way to communicate my problems with the community. I take no credit for the previous code.

Comment: @sebastian do you have any input on the solution you provided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Joe Kington](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309596/matplotlib-is-not-recognizing-the-attribute-set-xdata/24310618?noredirect=1#comment37575845_24310618) pointed out: plot returns a list of artists of which you want the first element:

```
self.line = self.widget.canvas.ax.plot(self.ValueTotal,'r-')[0]
```

So, taking the first list element, which is the actual line.

A minimal example to replicate this behavior:

```
l = plt.plot(range(3))[0]
l.set_xdata(range(3, 6))

l = plt.plot(range(3))
l.set_xdata(range(3, 6))
```

The first one runs fine and the second one gives the AttributeError.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. Out of curiosity, is set_xdata setting the x coordinate of a single point in the line?

Comment: @AndreScholich - Just FYI: It's not an API change. `plot` has always returned a list of artists, as it can be used to plot multiple lines.  It's more likely a typo in the original example.

Comment: @sudobangbang - No, it's setting the x coordinates of all points in the line.  (Notice that a sequence is being passed into `set_xdata`.)

Comment: Ah I see! I've got it working now. Out of curiosity @JoeKington is there a way in which I can set boundary on the graph window? For example, if I want to look at files per second but the x axis would only show in 10 second intervals. Right now it seems to keep expanding with no limit. (And when trying to look at data at 1 second when the xaxis is for 2500 seconds its a little bit taxing)

Comment: @sudobangbang - Either interactively zoom or use `xlim`.  (e.g. `plt.xlim([min, max])` or `ax.set_xlim([min, max])`)

Comment: The xlim works to a degree. Although it does handle the maximum size of a window, this does not increment. So at 2500 I want to see  2490-2500. Unfortunately, my implementation so far, has led xlim to cause the window to remain at 1-10 regardless if there are data-points beyond it.

Comment: @Joe Kington - Thanks for pointing that out. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The idiom to do that is:

```
x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
l, = plt.plot(x,x*x)
l.set_xdata(range(3, 6))
```

It takes the first element of Line2D list, which allows to manipulate the whole list of coordinates using `set_xdata()` and `set_ydata()`.

Note that this does not work:

```
x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
l,_ = plt.plot(x,x*x)
l.set_xdata(range(3, 6))
```

(Seeing the idiom with `line, =` in many code examples I used to think that `plot()` returns a pair of values, which is not true).